# PDO Zero-indexed when using Integer keys with FETCH_KEY_PAIR

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to use the `PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR` parameter in a PDO `fetchAll()` to be able to output an array where each key is the primary key and the value is another field of each row returned by the SELECT statement.

So for example:

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare('SELECT country_id, name FROM _country');
$stmt->execute();
$data = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);
```

where country_id is an INT(10) and name is a VARCHAR. The `$data` is then processed in another script:

```
foreach( $data as $key => $value ){
        echo $key . "|" . $value;
    }
```

SELECT statement result:

```
 ------------------------
 |country_id | name     |
 ------------------------
 | 18        | India    |
 | 26        | Germany  |
 | 129       | Sweden   |
 ------------------------
```

However, when the array is returned the keys are zero-indexed, only using the name column as the value.

Expected output (using `echo print_r($data)`)

```
Array ( [18] => India [26] => Germany [129] => Sweden)
```

Actual output

```
Array ( [0] => India [1] => Germany [2] => Sweden)
```

Curiously, when I switch the columns:

```
SELECT name, country_id FROM _country;
```

it works perfectly returning each country name as a key with the primary key integer as the value.

```
Array ( [India] => 18 [Germany] => 26 [Sweden] => 129)
```

I thought i'd try playing around with the `PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES` and `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` attributes, but to no avail.

I'm running:
- php 5.5.9
- mysql server 5.6.16
- pdo_mysql mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev

Comment: *the array is returned the keys are zero-indexed* would you mind showing us?

Comment: @revo - no problem, i've updated the question with expected and actual output.

Comment: @IbrahimShendy I'm not 100% sure what you mean - the country_id's in the database start from 1, but the results always start from 0. Like you say, i expected the country_id to be assigned to the key and the 'name' to the value, but when i filter the select statement similar to the table above, it still starts from 0. It's like it's assigning its own key and completely ignoring country_id.

Comment: @Gothic_Anatomist Take a look at my answer: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50783988/4365678)

Answer (score 0):

Try this way of fetching your result:

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare('SELECT country_id, name FROM _country');
$stmt->execute();
$data = array_map('key_value', $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP|PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));

function key_value($value){
    return $value[0]['name'];
}
```

`PDO::FETCH_GROUP|PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` returns an array of arrays. Then I mapped the resulting array to a function and generated only the desired output, which should be at your end:

`Array ( [18] => India [26] => Germany [129] => Sweden)`

I actually tried to generate your result using the `\PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR` parameter but it worked just fine. I don't know what the problem is!